# I have written a grammar in Antlr and I want to check if some expressions do or do not parse according to the Grammar

Tags: parsing, expression, antlr, antlr4

I have written a BNF Grammar in Antlr4. Using Antlr commands I managed to run it and compile it. The outputs are all the necessary files that Antlr generates (Lexers, Parsers, Listeners). I am not sure if the BNF grammar I created is semantically correct, but at least it is syntactically correct, since no errors appear.

At this point, I have to check if some existing expressions parse according to that grammar, but I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: I think you will find this book to be very helpful:  http://www.amazon.com/The-Definitive-ANTLR-4-Reference/dp/1934356999

Answer (score 0):

I'm making the following assumptions:

- antlr-4.1-complete.jar is in your CLASSPATH
- Your grammar is called 'Test'
- Your starting rule is called 'parse'

Then do the following:

```
$ java org.antlr.v4.runtime.misc.TestRig Test parse -tree
Type expressions here
CTL^D
```

If you have an example expression in a file, you can pipe the contents through the parser:

```
$ cat fileName | java org.antlr.v4.runtime.misc.TestRig Test parse -tree
```